# GSuite group to manage testers on Play console

Tags: android, google-workspace, google-play-console

Can we use a GSuite group for managing testers for a testing channel on Google Play Console? I was able to use Google Groups but that does not provide an API to add/remove testers. [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) does provide this. When I create a GSuite group and try to use that, I get an error saying "No Group or Community Found".

Comment: did you manage to use a GSuite Group for android testing?

Answer (score 0):

All of the documentation [is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).

Specifically it says in "Step 1 Set up test details" under "Closed test: manage testers with Google Groups or Google+ Communities":

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left-hand menu, select Release management > App releases.
4. Next to the closed track, select Manage.
5. Expand the 'Manage testers' section. If the 'Manage testers' section is empty, make sure that you've uploaded an APK or app bundle.
6. Next to 'Test method', select Alpha Testing using Google Groups or Google+ Communities.
7. Type the Google Group email address or Google+ Community URL in one of the following formats:

   - Google Groups: yourgroupname@googlegroups.com
   - Google+ Community: https://plus.google.com/communities/123456789012345678901
8. Copy the 'Opt-in URL' to share with your testers.
9. **If you're setting up a test within an organisation, enter an organisation ID and name in the 'Organisations' section.**
10. Select Save.

You might also want the information at the top of the page:

- Add organisations to a test

  - To add testers associated with an organisation that uses managed Google Play, go to your app's Pricing & distribution page and tick the box next to 'Turn on advanced managed Google Play features'.